# SQLDataSource Parameter not working

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have the following SQLDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MySqlDataSource" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:RmaReportingConnectionString %>' 
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Team] FROM [Locations] WHERE ([Team] IN (@Teams))">
        <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="Teams" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In code behind calling it like this:

```
MySqlDataSource.SelectParameters["Teams"].DefaultValue = "'Team 1','Team 2'";
MySqlDataSource.DataBind();
```

The issue is that I am not getting any results and I have a feeling it is due to syntax because if I run the raw SQL without the Parameter it works fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to use parameters with the `IN` clause. I'm not answering as I'm not 100% positive, but that would explain why it works as raw SQL

Comment: Possible, due to the '' characters. if not then what could be an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the escape characters (') in your string.

Try adding an @ sign before your variable string:

```
MySqlDataSource.SelectParameters["Teams"].DefaultValue = @"'Team 1','Team 2'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Team] FROM [Locations] WHERE ([Team] IN (@Teams))
```

this will only return 1 result. you need to mention all conditions like

```
 SELECT DISTINCT [Team] FROM [Locations] WHERE ([Team] IN (@Team1,@Team2,@Team3))
```